# Is it safe to use an enamel/cast iron Dutch oven with small cracks and worn enamel

Tags: equipment, cookware, dutch-oven, safety

I have a few-years old enamel/cast iron Dutch oven. I haven’t looked after it that well, and the inside is showing small cracks (crazing), and there is some grey discolouration which looks almost like the enamel is worn off in places. It isn’t chipped or visibly damaged, but looks worn.[image]

Is this safe to continue using?

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/108683/67

Answer (score 1):

I see bare metal that is partially seasoned -perfectly fine

Crazing of enamel is also fine. Rule of thumb: if you can feel cracks with fingernail then that's too much a trap for pathogens.

An occasional soak in borax or vinegar to be 100%

Comment: I've been told that the modern non-stick surfaces (e.g., teflon) are not healthy at all if they become scratched. From your answer, it seems you're saying old-school enamel cast-iron dutch ovens do NOT suffer from the same health risks after being damaged. Yes?